How can I plot the edge graph of osmnx with different line sizes and different filters
I try to plot a map of edges with different line thickness in osmnx. I have found this idea for colors How does osmnx.plot_graph determine which edges get which colors? but I cannot adapt it for the line width.
I have got the following code:
@dataclass
class NetworkType:
    linewidth: float
    alpha: float
    color: str
    networkfilter: str


fl = [
        NetworkType(1, 1, "black", '["highway"~"motorway|motorway_link|trunk|trunk_link"]'),
        NetworkType(0.75, 1, "black", '["highway"~"primary|primary_link"]'),
        NetworkType(0.5, 1, "black", '["highway"~"secondary|secondary_link"]'),
        NetworkType(0.25, 1, "black", '["highway"~"tertiary|tertiary_link"]'),
        NetworkType(0.125, 1, "black", '["highway"~"residential|living_street|service|track|road|path"]'),
]


def network_plot(ai) -> None:
    for i in fl:
        try:
            g = osmnx.graph_from_polygon(polygon, custom_filter=i.networkfilter)
            _, edges = osmnx.graph_to_gdfs(g)
            edges.plot(ax=ai, color=i.color, linewidth=i.linewidth, alpha=i.alpha)
        except:
            pass


My goal is that I get the road network and based on the road type the line width and the colors are different and I can plot a single image, so that e.g. highways have got a thicker line than living streets.
But on my current solution it seems that the different plots are not aligned on the correct position within the image.
Thanks for help
